# IntelliJ: System bash and IntelliJ bash are not the same

Tags: bash, ubuntu, intellij-idea, terminal

I use **IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 CE** on **Pop!_OS 20.04** with **bash 5.0.17**.

Problem in a sentence: I set IntelliJ terminal to `/bin/bash` via the IntelliJ settings (with and without `-i` flag) and some commands work while others refuse.

```
bash: vi: command not found
```

Obvious inconsistencies: `vi` in regular terminal works fine and appears in `/usr/bin/`, but no chance to find it via IntelliJ terminal. Even though the `PATH` differ in both terminals, the IntelliJ terminal denies the existence of vi, sudo, apt and others. `nano` works for example. Funny thing here:

`which nano` in **system** termianl returns: `/usr/bin/nano`

`which nano` in **IntelliJ** terminal returns: `/usr/sbin/nano`

Putting a `vi` link or copy to `sbin` or somewhere else did not help. In my home directory the IntelliJ termianl finds the `vi` file but can not run it (link: "does not exist", copy: "missing libraries"). Updating the `PATH` in IntelliJ termianl works but this does not help if certain files disappear.

How to fix it and make IntelliJ terminal follow my system's setup?

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be a question. And if there was, the IntelliJ team may be better versed to answer it.

Comment: I think that any possible answer will be based on your statement: "I set IntelliJ terminal to `/bin/bash`", but with the additional information: how did you do that?

Comment: @BeUndead Thanks, I added a final question and contacted the IntelliJ team as well. So the solution will be added here by me if found.

Comment: @Dominique Thanks, clarified that in problem description.

Comment: What does `which bash` in your non-IntelliJ terminal return? What dotfiles are you using to configure your terminal (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc)?

Comment: @jeremysprofile `which bash` returns /usr/bin/bash. I tried that bash path in IntelliJ settings as well, no difference. Usually I configure my bash in /etc/profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to your original installation, e.g. snap, flatpak, and so on. There may be differences in the case of the bash version.

You can try to install IntelliJ IDEA manually from the [downloads page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux), `cd /bin` and execute `./idea.sh`. It should pick-up correctly your bash and variables.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works fine out of the box.